# want to show country flag with visitor count asp.net

Tags: asp.net

in my asp.net form i want to show country flag along with current visitor count. when user visit our site from USA then USA flag count will be increase by one and when the same user close his browser or go to another site then count will be decrease. please give me the best logic to show current visitor count country wise along with country flag. need help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem here is this - you can't rely on the event of closing the browser.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/58835/Window-Close-Event-of-Browser

However, you can try to get at least approximate results. In the article above you see how to react on these events. I'd use ajax to communicate with the server to increment/decrement the values as needed, updating the relevant parts of the page in the process. For storage, you can use database to store these values for instance.

Look here for more info on ajax with jquery in asp.net: http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/ajax-basics-with-jquery-in-asp.net/ If it isn't enough for you, use google, there are plenty resources out there waiting for you.